# How to make my loop assign the remainder of a line, including spaces, to a variable, before going to the next line

Tags: c++

I've been tasked by my instructor to create a banking Transactions log for my project. It needs to do several things, but I'm focusing on extracting the information before focusing on the specifics of the projects formatting, but I'm not sure how to extract the information correctly.

For the most part, I'm getting what I need, however, the last variable is called "Payee" and I can't get the loop to assign all of the remainder of the line.

This is what the File that's being read looks like. There's a total of 9 lines, with no blank lines in-between:

```
0123456 1 101.32 10-25-2017 11-15-2017
002345678901 1 3343 110.00 10-25-2017 Triceratops Fashions
012345678901 3 0 128.00 10-27-2017 Cash
022345678901 6 0 900.00 10-27-2017 PowerBoulder Lottery
032345678901 1 3345 200.00 10-27-2017 Bedrock Furniture
042345678901 2 0 21.12 10-27-2017 Bedrock Bowling
052345678901 3 0 300.00 11-01-2017 Slate Rock & Gravel
062345678901 5 0 100.00 11-02-2017 Pebbles College Fund
072345678901 4 0 30.00 11-05-2017 Cash
```

And this is my code:

```
int main()
{
ifstream infile;
ofstream warningfile;

infile.open("E:\\TRANSACTIONS.txt");
warningfile.open("E:\\WARNINGS.txt");

string AccountNum;
int AccountType;
float BeginBalance;
float EndBalance;
string BeginBalanceDate;
string StatementCloseDate;
string TransType;
string Payee;
string Payee2;

if (!infile)
    cout << "Error, no file called TRANSACTIONS to read";

while(infile >> AccountNum >> AccountType >> BeginBalance >> BeginBalanceDate >> StatementCloseDate >> Payee)
{ 
    
    if ( AccountType == 1)
    {TransType = "Check";
    }
    else if (AccountType == 2)
        {TransType = "Debit Card";
        }
    else if (AccountType == 3)
        {TransType = "Deposit";
        }
    else if (AccountType == 4)
        {TransType = "Withdrawl";
        }
    else if (AccountType == 5)
        {TransType = "Transfer Out";
        }
    else if (AccountType == 6)
        {TransType = "Transfer In";
        }   
    
    cout << AccountNum << "|" << TransType << "|" << BeginBalance << "|" << BeginBalanceDate << "|" << StatementCloseDate << "|" << Payee << endl;
}

infile.close();
warningfile.close();

//pause funciton

Pause();

return(0);
```

The screen prints this on code execution:

[image: Print Screen of Executed Code]

Here's the example finished product provided by the instructor:

[image: Example finished Product]

Comment: Instructor said he wants it like this :/

Comment: @TreyC Are you sure they didn't mean "Have the brace at a new line, by itself"? And no, they can't have said to put a brace between `else` and `if`... This is incredibly hard to read and if an instructor said that this is the way to go then there are not many days left until they are not anyone's instructor anymore.

Comment: Please post the input and output into the question as text (code), not as a link to an image. Links can become invalid over time, thereby making your question incomplete. Also, nobody can copy&paste your input from the image, in order to test it. You may want to read this: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Comment: I did for the input, but I'm not sure if I can from the console screen of the output.

Comment: It seems that "Payee" is an optional field, which is not always filled (at least in the first line it isn't). Are there any other fields that are optional?

Comment: No, that's the only one.

Comment: The format of the input file seems inconsistent. In the first line, the fourth field is a date, whereas in all other lines, it is a floating-point number.

Comment: I believe its because every line excluding the first has a transaction amount, and since the first has no payee/transaction, the field is not filled. I'm honestly stuck in the mud on this one. I have no idea where to even begin on it.

Comment: If the input format is inconsistent and has no clear rules, then the problem cannot be solved. Please specify the exact rules of the input format in the question. If they are unclear to you too, then you will have to ask your instructor.

Comment: I've edited the question description to include the example finished format the Teacher sent to me.

Comment: Based on the desired output that you have now posted in your most recent edit, it seems that "Payee" is not the only optional field. It seems that "Reference" is another optional field. However, it is still unclear why the first line has two dates.

Comment: My guess is that the first line contains different information than all the other lines and should be interpreted differently. Also, it seems that "Reference" is not an optional field, but exists in every line (except the first), but should only be printed if it is not zero.

Comment: Since you don't know the meaning of the first line, I suggest that you ignore and discard it for now, by writing `cin.ignore( 1000, '\n' );` before doing any input. However, I don't think that your posted code will work on the other lines, because you seem to be attempting to read two dates, but only the first line contains two dates; all the other lines contain only one date.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Payee` field has spaces in it, so you can't use `operator>>` to read it, use `std::getline()` instead:

```cpp
while ((infile >> AccountNum >> AccountType >> BeginBalance >> BeginBalanceDate >> StatementCloseDate) && std::getline(inFile, Payee))
```

Since your file data is line-based, I would instead suggest using only `std::getline()` to read the file, and use `std::istringstream` to parse each line, eg:

```cpp
...
std::string line;

while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    if ((iss >> AccountNum >> AccountType >> BeginBalance >> BeginBalanceDate >> StatementCloseDate) && std::getline(iss, Payee))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```